# Ember.js - Call parent model hook to load data for child

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, router, ember-router

I have a master/detail view in Ember. If i am calling the detail page directly, the model hook of the detail page needs the model(data) from the parent(master). The detail model hook is called - whats the proper way to get/call the model so the modelFor function in the detail hook works.

Router:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('index', { path: '/' } );
    this.resource('devices', { path: '/devices'}, function() {
        this.resource('device', { path: ':imei'});
    });
});
```

Master Route:

```
App.DevicesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {

        var self = this;
        return requestController.get({
            url: "foo/bar/",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("error");
                return [];
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Detail Route:

```
    App.DeviceRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(args) {
////// Gets Called - needs data from master!!
            var model = this.modelFor('devices.index').findBy('imei', args.imei);
            return model;
        }
    });
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `devices.index` route is not the parent route, it's another leaf route. Typically you would define the model on the resource route and then access through the leaf routes:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('index', { path: '/' } );
    this.resource('devices', { path: '/devices'}, function() {
        this.route('device', { path: ':imei'});
    });
});
```

Master route:

```
App.DevicesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {

        var self = this;
        return requestController.get({
            url: "foo/bar/",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("error");
                return [];
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Index route: (in future ember versions this will automatically pick up parent's model)

```
App.DevicesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        this.modelFor('devices');
    }
});
```

Detail route:

```
App.DevicesDeviceRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(args) {
        var model = this.modelFor('devices').findBy('imei', args.imei);
        return model;
    }
});
```